# Creating decal on collision Unity3d C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The below code is from a quick game I'm creating to test out the features of Unity.  I have the code creating a decal when it detects a collision with another object.

The issue is that the code creates the decal facing up (Y direction). I have tried a few solutions but can't get it to rotate to face the same direction as the object it strikes.

Example: An object hits a wall facing the player, obviously we would want the decal to spawn facing the player. My issue is that they all spawn face up.

I looked at a few older questions posted with similar issues but can't get it to cooperate so any help would be great.

UPDATE: Also forgot to mention as was pointed out that "Splat" is a prefab and GameObject type plane.  Also added a photo of the issue for context.

[image: Issue]

```
else
{
    Debug.Log ("collision detected");

    //Instantiate (splat, transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(collision.gameObject.transform.forward));
    Instantiate (splat, transform.position, Quaternion.LookRotation(collision.gameObject.transform.forward, collision.gameObject.transform.transform.up));

    //destroy gameObject, timer seconds
    Destroy(this.gameObject);
}
```

Comment: In your script I see "splat", I assume that is the `Prefab` that you want to spawn. Is that a `GameObject` you have made as a `Prefab` or is it an imported 3D model (fbx, skp, etc...)?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that, it is a prefab plane object with color at the moment.  The plane always spawns facing up (Y direction if thinking 2D).

Comment: Could that perhaps be because you're spawning it with a roation of `collision.gameObject.transform.transform.up`?

Comment: I have tried all kinds of combinations, the general idea is to get it to take on the same rotation of the gameobjects normal it collides with.

Comment: You don't want the rotation to be *the same as the object* you want it to be the same as *the surface normal.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## This is going to be tricky...

But possible.

Step 1: Get the triangle of the mesh that the collision occurred on.  According to [this answer](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/245482/mesh-polygon-of-a-hit-surface-on-a-gameobject.html) we can do that through a Raycast.  This is pretty straight forward.

Step 2: Get the surface normal of this triangle.

```
Mesh mesh = meshCollider.sharedMesh;
Vector3[] normals = mesh.normals;
```

Ok, good. We can get that data.  Presumably the index into this array that we want is the same as the `RaycastHit.triangleIndex` value from Step 1.  Do some tests with simple meshes (cubes, planes) just to make sure.

Step 3: Rotate.  You'll have to play with this one a bit in order to match the "up" direction on your prefab.  It would be an easy mistake to make Z+ your splat's visible face only for the math to be simpler if it was Y+.

Step 4: Account for the *worldspace* rotation of the object as a whole.  Once the splat prefab is rotated for the face (test step 3 on unrotated objects) add in the rotation applied to the object.

Note that objects that are themselves children of other objects may have several layers of rotation and scale applied (hence the emphasis on worldspace values), all of which could easily throw off the result.  Start with simple cases and add in the variations one step at a time. Maybe you can skip checking for scale because you'll always use uniformly scaled objects in your scene.